# "None but the brave deserves the fair." What part of speech is "but"?

Tags: prepositions, adverbs, conjunctions, parts-of-speech

In the sentence:

> None **but** the brave deserves the fair.

...is the word *but* here a:

1. pronoun
2. adverb
3. preposition
4. conjunction

Normally *but* is used as conjunction, but here I am not sure if this *"but"* is used as a conjunction or not. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: This is a special meaning of _but_  that means 'except (for)' that occurs only with negatives.  It's archaic and reserved for homilies like this. You could call _but_ a preposition here if you wanted to. But there's not much difference between adverbs, prepositions, and conjunctions except for how they're structured in a given sentence.

Comment: Thanks . That is the problem with MCQs . Options are so close and always create confusion.

Comment: @NeilK I've given some rule of thumb tests you can use in my answer below.

Comment: I would say "but" in this use is an adverb having the sense of "only".http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/but_3

Comment: @rogermue *But* means *except* or *apart from* here. It doesn't mean *only*, it seems.

Comment: The source of the line is Dryden's "Alexander's Feast" from 1697, so the old-fashioned diction is honestly come by.

Answer (score 4):

> In the sentence:
>
> > None **but** the brave deserves the fair.
>
> ...is the word *but* here a:
>
> 1. pronoun
> 2. adverb
> 3. preposition
> 4. conjunction

### **1: Pronoun**

*But* is never a pronoun.

### **2: Adverb**

*But*, the adverb, means something similar to *only*. If you take the word out completely the sentence will always be perfectly formed. Consider the following:

- You can but try.
- You can only try.
- You can try.

or ...

- Life is but a dream.
- Life is only a dream
- Life is a dream.

or ...

- He is but a beginner
- He is only a beginner.
- He is a beginner.

or ...

- We have but three days left.
- We have only three days left.
- We have three days left.

Notice that if the sentence with *but* is true, the sentence without *but* will also be true. The adverb *but* does not change the truth conditions for a sentence.

### **3: Preposition**

*But* the preposition means *apart from*. We often see it heading a preposition phrase used as a postmodifier in a noun phrase:

- all [but one]
- everyone [but James]
- nothing [but an excuse]

Notice that this *but* phrase does indeed change the absolute meaning of the sentence. The following sentences do not mean the same thing at all. Their truth conditions are completely different:

- Everyone was captured.
- Everyone but James was captured.

We can normally substitute the preposition *but* with *apart from*:

- Everyone apart from James was captured.

A quite useful test is to see if *including* will give the opposite meaning:

- Everyone but James was captured.
- Everyone including James was captured.

In the sentences above, the fact that the preposition *including* gives the opposite meaning tells us that it is probably the preposition. Note that this test doesn't work if the word following *but* is a number:

- All including one ... (doesn't work because of the numeral)

Notice that when we have *but* as a preposition, it does not change the Head of the noun phrase. In the noun phrase *no one but Bob*, the Head of the phrase is  *no one*. The phrase *but Bob* is modifying our understanding of *no one*.

### **4: Conjunction**

The conjunction (or co-ordinator) *but* is the most common *but* that we see. It can always be substituted with the conjunction *and* and the sentence will still be truthful.  Consider:

- I hit Bill but not Bob.
- I hit Bill and not Bob.

or ...

- My elephant is small but strong.
- My elephant is small and strong.

### **The Original Poster's sentence**

> None but the brave  deserves the fair.

Let's try some tests. Can we substitute it with *only*, *apart from* or *and*:

- None only the brave deserves the fair.
- None apart from the brave deserves the fair.
- None and the brave deserves the fair.

The last sentence is not good. The meaning is different. In fact it seems to be contradictory. More importantly, the grammar is bad. We would expect a plural verb here, if we could make sense of the Subject in the first place. This cannot be the conjunction.

Now, the first sentence seems kind of marginally acceptable. The second is definitely ok. This means that it could still be *but* the adverb or *but* the preposition. Let's see if we can remove the word *but*. If it is the adverb, the sentence should be grammatical, and have the same truth conditions:

- *None the brave deserves the fair.

This shows that this is definitely not the adverb *but*. The sentence is completely ungrammatical. It is so ungrammatical we cannot know what it means. If it was *but* the adverb, the sentence would still make perfect sense.

It seems it must be *but* the preposition. Let's see whether taking out the *but* phrase changes the meaning. It should do:

- None but the brave deserves the fair.
- None deserves the fair.

Yes the meaning has changed here. Lastly if we use *including* instead of *but* does it give the opposite meaning:

- None, including the brave, deserves the fair.

Yes, this worked too. This is definitely *but* the preposition.

Answer (score -3):

> None but the brave deserves the fair.

*But* is always a conjunction.  "None but the brave" is a noun phrase, and *but* conjoins the two nouns in it, "none" and "the brave".

Consider instead:

> Jack and Jill went up the hill.

*And* is a conjunction joining "Jack" and "Jill".  Now consider:

> All but three people left the room.

It's still obvious that *but* is a conjunction within the subject noun-phrase, right?  It's the same in "None but the brave".