# They or them following "nobody but"

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

Which one is grammatically correct: "Nobody but them was present there." or "Nobody but they were present there."?

Comment: I'm sure there is a grammatically correct sentence that can be structured like this, but it might be easier to rewrite it to "Only they were present,"

Comment: This is quite similar to your previous question, isn't it? Maybe you could explain what you think the difference is: [None but (they/them) is/are](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/399815)

Answer (score 0):

This usage of [but](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/but) is as a preposition. Therefore, it takes an object (they/them) in the objective case. The correct word to use here is *them*: "Nobody but **them** was present there."

Note that the subject of the sentence is *nobody*, not the personal pronoun; therefore, the correct form of the verb is the third-person singular, *was*, instead of *were*.

Comment: I think it's more complicated than that. You can't say *nobody were ...,* so *nobody but they were ...* is ungrammatical. On the other hand, you can say *none were*, and *none but they were* seems to be used.   I can find *none but they were* and *nobody but them was* in Google books, with *none* and *nobody* subjects; but not the other way around.